# Том Сойер и Санкт-Петербург

Tags: литература, орфоэпия

Том Сойер из книги Марка Твена был родом из маленького городка Санкт-Петербурга. А как называются жители этого города: *петербуржцы, санктпетербуржцы, петербургцы* или *санктпетербургцы*?

Comment: Вопрос некорректный. 
Город называется Санкт-Петербургом только в переводе.

Comment: А мне именно в переводном варианте и интересно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Том Сойер из книги Марка Твена был родом из маленького городка Санкт-Петербурга.

Процитирую статью англ. Википедии [*"Том Сойер"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Sawyer).

"He lives with his half brother Sid, his cousin Mary, and his stern Aunt Polly in the (fictional) town of St. Petersburg, Missouri."

Что в переводе означает:
"Он живёт (...) **в (выдуманном) городе** St. Petersburg, Миссури".

**Так что, строго говоря, нет такого города.**

**P.S.** Правда существует вполне реальный St. Petersburg в штате Флорида, город-побратим российского Санкт-Петербурга. Но, к примеру та же Википедия :) уклончиво называет его обитателей просто *жители города*. Что и Вам могу посоветовать. :-)

Comment: Процитирую Fuchoin Kazuki

>название этого города произносится по-английски: Сент-Питерсбери

St. Petersburg. На мой взгляд, **-burg** в конце этого слова лучше написать русскими буквами без "и". Т.е. *бёр*, а лучше *бёрг* или *берг*.

Сент-Питерсбёрг или Сейнт-Питерсбёрг.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, название этого города произносится по-английски: Сент-Питерсбери, а не по-немецки, как наш Питер. И, думается мне, что тут нет какого-то правила для названия жителей — как не скрути, все равно получается криво. Поэтому предлагаю писать просто: "жители Сент-Питерсбери".

Comment: В переводе Тома Сойера был именно Санкт-Петербург.

Comment: Проверил как произносят Petersburg американцы. Фонетическая транскрипция [piːtərzbərɡ] На картах город Petersburg в Западной Виргинии обозначают как Питерсберг, но судя по [произношению](http://ru.forvo.com/word/petersburg/#en) вариант @Nikolja ближе к истине, чем официальное название.

Answer (score 0):

Питсбургцы.
И неча огород городить.